# When is graph closed and relation of it with continuity of the function

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separable-spaces

The following question was part of my Topology assignment and I was unable to solve 2  parts out of 4.

> Question:Let $X\times Y$ be topological spaces where $Y$ is Hausdorff. Let $X\times Y$ be the given product topology. Then for a function $f: X \to Y$ which of the following statements are true.

A If graph of $f$ is closed in $X\times Y$, then $f$ is continuous.

B If graph $f$ is closed in $X\times Y$, then $f$ need not be continuous.

I am unable to think how I can relate graph with continuity as graph is just a set in $X\times Y$.

I am not good in topology. So, your help is required.

Answer

> Only B is correct.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: let $f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x}&x\neq 0\\ 0&x=0\end{cases}$. Is the graph closed?

Comment: Think of a graph of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ by visualizing at as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Can you think of such a graph which is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @Caffeine Ya , but function is not continuous ! Am i right?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is not continuous (provided $\Bbb R$ is endowed with the usual topology).